Primitive polynomial for non-prime $\mathbb{F}_q$
I need to computationally find (at least one) primitive element $\theta$ of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$, where $q=p^k$ is a prime power for some prime $p$. The goal is to express all the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ as power of $\theta$ in order to compute some discrete logarithms. For context, this is required to generate the so-called $B_h$ sets of integers (1).
I have a straightfoward procedure (based on the previous article) for prime $q=p$ for obtaining the field extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. In that case, I just use the Conway polynomials $f_{p,n}$ for obtaining a primitive element $\theta$ for $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Then, I can easily derive all the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ (expressed as $n$-vectors of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$) as powers of $\theta$. It is quite practical to use Conway's polynomials as primitive polynomials, as they have been extensively tabulated (2) and do not require other computations on my side.
However, extending this "procedure" for non-prime $q$ has been quite troublesome for me.
Some issues:

I cannot find anywhere the "equivalent" of a Conway polynomial (or any primitive polynomial, for what is worth) for non-prime $q$. This might seem a bit naive, but from my understanding, I need a primitive polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ for extending it to $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$. This is also somewhat more complicated computationally as $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ is not equivalent to a vector space on $Z_{q}$ (which is in general not a field) but it's elements are those of the (already extended) field $\mathbb{F}_{q}=\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$. I have found some ideas here 3, but the author comes up with a primitive polynomial for $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ (in particular $\mathbb{F}_{4})$ without explaining how it can be found in practice.
Does considering the field extension $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ as $\mathbb{F}_{p^{nk}}$ instead help in any way?

Just an example to be practical. Let's consider $\mathbb{F}_{3^6}$. The Conway polynomial is $x^6 + 2x^4 + x^2 + x + 2$. I can computationally find the expression of all the elements (apart from 0, clearly) of $\mathbb{F}_{3^6}$ either as powers of one its roots $\theta$ or as 5-th degree polynomials (i.e. 6-vectors) in $\theta$. For $\mathbb{F}_{9^3}$ (which should be the same field), I would have no clue on how to go on.
PS: As you probably can deduce from the question, I am not a mathematician by trade so my understanding of finite field theory is basic at best (but willing to learn more).
Sorry in advance for the sloppy language and thanks for your patience.

Update: Using the suggested answers, I think I have solved the issue as follows.
I use the Conway polynomial $f_{p,nk}$ to generate $\mathbb{F}_{p^{nk}}$ as the usual list of vectors with $p^{nk}$ components in $\mathbb{F}_{p}\sim \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ (or as powers of a primitive element $\theta$). In this way, to do additions of elements in the field I can just sum the corresponding vectors modulo $p$ and to do multiplications I just need to sum the corresponding powers of the primitive element modulo $p^{nk}-1$. All the other primitive elements can be found as $\theta^s$, where $s$ is a number coprime to $p^{nk}-1$.
Then, I use the following property (e.g. see 4): a field $\mathbb{F}_{p^v}$ contains a single subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^u}$ for each $u$ dividing $v$. If $\theta$ is a primitive element for $\mathbb{F}_{p^v}$ (i.e. generates $\mathbb{F}_{p^v}^*$), the smallest power of $\theta$ that generates $\mathbb{F}_{p^u}^*$ is $r=\frac{p^v-1}{p^u-1}$.
Applying it to the previous case yields that $\theta^r$ with $r=\frac{p^{nk}-1}{p^{k}-1}$ generates $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}^*$ (i.e. $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}^*$ is represented by $\theta^0,\theta^r, \theta^{2r}, \dots \theta^{(q-2)r}$).
Working out the example: for $\mathbb{F}_{9^3}$, I consider it as  $\mathbb{F}_{3^6}$  instead and find a primitive element $\theta$ using the Conway's polynomial $f_{3,6}$ and a representation of the whole field in terms of the primitive element. Considering the subfield $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ gives $r=\frac{3^6-1}{3^2-1}=91$. Therefore the representation of $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{3^6}$ is $0,\theta^0=1, \theta^{91}, \theta^{181}, \theta^{273}, \theta^{364}, \theta^{455}, \theta^{546},\theta^{638}$ (where $\theta$ is a primitive element for $\mathbb{F}_{3^6}$).

For a non-mathematician, you have a very solid grasp of these topics!

Thanks for the kind words.

Short answer: if we can factor polynomials over non-prime fields, then we can find primitive polynomials for them using primitive polynomials for prime fields.
Let $q=p^k$; we want to find a primitive polynomial for $\Bbb F_{q^n}$ as an extension of $\Bbb F_q$. It's equivalent to find a polynomial over $\Bbb F_q$ having a root in $\Bbb F_{q^n}$ that generates it.
Take the Conway polynomial $f_{p,nk}$, which has $nk$ roots in $\Bbb F_{p^{nk}} = \Bbb F_{q^n}$ that generate it. Now factor $f_{p,nk}$ as a polynomial in $\Bbb F_q$; let $F_{q,n}$ be any one of its irreducible factors. All the roots of $F_{q,n}$ still generate $\Bbb F_{p^{nk}} = \Bbb F_{q^n}$, and so $F_{q,n}$ is a primitive polynomial for $\Bbb F_{q^n}$ over $\Bbb F_q$.

This comment definitely pointed me in the (seemingly) correct direction! Thanks.

If $q$ is not too large, there is a simple series of tests. Find all the prime factors of $q-1$, and then raise a candidate primitive element to all combinations of those prime factors except all of them.
Using $GF(2^8)$ as an example, the prime factors of $2^8-1 = 255$ are  {$3,5,17$}. The combinations are $3 \cdot 5 = 15$, $3 \cdot 17 = 51$, $5 \cdot 17 = 85$. Then the test for primitive element $e$ in $GF(2^8)$ is: $e^{15} \ne 1$ and $e^{51} \ne 1$ and $e^{85} \ne 1$.
There are totient($q-1$) primitive elements for $GF(q)$. For $GF(2^8)$, 128 primitive elements.
